# Multiple copies of React in my Application

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-treelist component and inside that i am using office-ui-fabric callout(its like a tooltip) component to have a tooltip on elements in tree structure when i am running this program it runs correctly but when i am bundling and using the bundle file in my project as a module it gives error:-

Exception in Layer.componentDidUpdate(): Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded

I have tried many solutions from diff forum but none of them worked.I am sure problem is of multiple copies of react.

Details of what i did

I cloned react-treelist from github then i installed office-ui-fabric module then i changed some code to make callout component work with react-treelist, i did npm start it worked fine the i did npm run dist and copied the bundle file to my project directory inside a folder named react-treelist and then imported that file as module in my code and ran the code it gave me the above error.

Can anybody suggest me how to accomplish the above task without having multiple copies of react in my application

Answer (score 1):

If you use webpack to build your application, you can use the [`resolve.alias` configuration option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) to make sure that all modules refer to the same `react` library:

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react': fs.realpathSync('node_modules/react'),
      'react-dom': fs.realpathSync('node_modules/react-dom')
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering

I tried your solution but it didn't work

Also i tried this
resolve: {
        
        extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
        
     
        alias: {
        react: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react')
        }

Answer (score 1):

If you use web pack then you can fix it by adding the following to Webpack config

```
externals: {
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
}
```

Comment: and if you don't use webpack?